# Linear regression model of a power function with two terms (y=ax^b+cx^d) in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am attempting to find the relationship between sustained wind speed and wind gust multipliers [gust multiplier = (wind gust value) / (sustained wind speed)]. I initially used a power model (y = ax^b) and linear regression to model them, but I would like to attempt to fit the data to a power model with two terms (y = ax^b + cx^d) as well.

In the power model with one term, I was able to take the log of each variable and then that allowed me to save the coefficients (a and b values) for the power model. I am unsure of how to alter my code to be able to create a power model with two terms.

```
model = lm(log(data$GustMult)~log(data$SusWindSpeed))  # not sure how to change for a power model with two terms
coefs = unname(coef(model))
coefa = exp(coefs[1])
coefb = coefs[2]
coefc = exp(coefs[3])  #added for new model
coefd = coefs[4]  #added for new model
rsquared = summary(model)$r.squared
```

I attempted to run the code as it is above, however that only provides the values for the a and b coefficients still.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions you may have!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It’s easier to help if you make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Comment: I don't have a proof for you, but I strongly suspect that this is not identified, meaning that you cannot find a *unique* set of parameters (a,b,c,d) that best fit this model to the data.  The canonical example is trying to identify a and b from y = c + (a+b)x. In this example, there are an infinite number of combinations of a and b that would, e.g., minimize a sum of squared errors.  I suspect you have a similar issue with your proposed model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think DanY might be right, that there is no unique set of parameters that would fit this model. In any case, I think you would need to fit this as a non-linear model.

I have no idea what your data looks like, but let's say it's something like this:

```r
set.seed(69)

SusWindSpeed <- rgamma(1000, 2, .125)
GustMult  <- (-0.98)*SusWindSpeed^(0.12) + (0.1)*SusWindSpeed^(-0.32) + rnorm(1000, 3, 0.025)
data <- data.frame(SusWindSpeed, GustMult)

plot(data$SusWindSpeed, data$GustMult)
```

[image]

Then you could try fitting a non-linear model like this:

```r
modA <- nls(GustMult ~ var_a * SusWindSpeed^var_b + var_c * SusWindSpeed^var_d + Const,
            start = list(var_a = -1, var_b = 0.1, var_c = 0.1, var_d = -0.3, Const = 3),
            data = data,
            control = list(maxiter = 500))

summary(modA)
#> 
#> Formula: GustMult ~ var_a * SusWindSpeed^var_b + var_c * SusWindSpeed^var_d + 
#>     Const
#> 
#> Parameters:
#>       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> var_a -1.28314    0.72635  -1.767   0.0776 .  
#> var_b  0.10381    0.04387   2.367   0.0181 *  
#> var_c  0.01506    0.03884   0.388   0.6983    
#> var_d -1.45958    3.32064  -0.440   0.6604    
#> Const  3.38496    0.76287   4.437 1.01e-05 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.02452 on 995 degrees of freedom
#> 
#> Number of iterations to convergence: 22 
#> Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.379e-07
```

And we can show that this is a reasonable fit:

```
test_SusWindSpeed <- seq(0, 60, 0.05)

plot.new()
plot(data$SusWindSpeed, data$GustMult)
points(test_SusWindSpeed, 
       predict(modA, newdata = list(SusWindSpeed = test_SusWindSpeed)), 
       col = "red")
```

[image]

However, you might find you struggle to get this model to converge, or that you get different results with different start parameters.

<sup>Created on 2020-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>